# IF statement with AND as well as OR operators PHP

Tags: php

I have the following if statement

```
if (isset($part->disposition) and ($part->disposition=='attachment'))
```

Problem is the second part of that statement, i also need to include this;

```
($part->disposition=='inline')
```

The statement needs to work if the disposition is attachment or if its inline.

Comment: could not understand your question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doesn't that work:

```
if (isset($part->disposition) and (($part->disposition=='attachment') or ($part->disposition=='inline')))
```

Comment: This worked and was first so you get win. Thanks all for the prompt help and the diff methods!

Answer (score 6):

This must help:

```
if (isset($part->disposition) && ($part->disposition=='attachment' || $part->disposition=='inline'))
```

Comment: @Kitson it is my habit to write cleaner code. Easy to understand for others, with proper indentation, line spacing, correct use of braces, brackets, etc. :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you may be going to have more than two options in the future you might also be interested in [in_array(needle, haystack)](http://docs.php.net/in_array)

```
if (
  isset($part->disposition)
  && in_array($part->disposition, array('attachment', 'inline', 'option3', 'option4'))
)
```

If you want the equivalent of === (strict comparison, instead of == like in your example) set the third parameter of in_array() to true.

Answer (score 2):

This try <del>(for efficiency)</del>:

```
if (isset($part->disposition))
{
    if($part->disposition=='attachment' || $part->disposition=='inline')
    {
        // perform task
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this more efficient? Won't the second statement be ignored if the first is false - when they are put together - and hence be equally efficient?